# Independently scrolling divs using tailwind and sticky

Tags: css, scroll, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble getting the right, "Scroll independently", div, to scroll independently of its sibling div to its left. I would like to be able to do this without changing anything outside of the `<!-- CONTENT START --> <!-- CONTENT END -->` comments. It seems to be close, but I'm stuck. The "Scroll" and "Scroll independently" div's always scroll together. I'm running this in https://play.tailwindcss.com/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="flex bg-gray-100 justify-center">
  <div class="flex flex-col w-full max-w-5xl pb-7">
    <nav class="sticky top-0 flex items-center justify-between bg-gray-700 text-white h-16 z-40 p-2">
      <div class="flex w-1/3">
        {Left}
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center  w-1/3">
        {Middle}
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-end items-center w-1/3 gap-2">
        {Right}
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- CONTENT START -->
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-2/3">
        <div class="sticky top-16 w-full h-20 mb-2 bg-green-500">
          Don't scroll
        </div>
        <div class="w-full h-96 mb-2 bg-red-500">
          Scroll
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-1/3 mb-2 h-[1000px] bg-pink-400">
        Scroll independently
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT END -->


    
    <footer class="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-50 bg-gray-700 h-7">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-end px-8 pt-1">
        <div class="text-sm text-white">{versionStr}</div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so the right 'independent' column stays on screen when scrolling the entire page content? It's [pretty easy to do](https://play.tailwindcss.com/imdA43CzrV) if you're okay with that div going away when the page scrolls. If you're looking to have it stay on screen while scrolling then you can add sticky to that right column as well https://play.tailwindcss.com/Qg2vAlQSur

Comment: @JHeth, your second solution is pretty darn close. Thanks. I do want that right column to scroll independently from the left, which your play is doing, except at some point the right column scroll causes the left to scroll too,  which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: That's just a matter of overscroll behavior. Adding overscroll-contain to the right scrolling container removes that double scrolling like here https://play.tailwindcss.com/Dbd5vnExhk

Comment: Excellent, thanks again @JHeth

Comment: Happy to help! You can share your findings + final solution as an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer to help people who might have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 5):

This cleaned it up nicely:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/Dbd5vnExhk

```html
<div class="flex bg-gray-100 justify-center">
  <div class="flex flex-col w-full max-w-5xl pb-7">
    <nav class="sticky top-0 flex items-center justify-between bg-gray-700 text-white h-16 z-40 p-2">
      <div class="flex w-1/3">
        {Left}
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center  w-1/3">
        {Middle}
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-end items-center w-1/3 gap-2">
        {Right}
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- CONTENT START -->
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-2/3">
        <div class="sticky top-16 w-full h-20 bg-green-500">
          Don't scroll
        </div>
        <div class="w-full h-[2000px] bg-gradient-to-b from-red-300 to-red-800">
          Scroll
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-1/3 h-[calc(100vh-5.75rem)] sticky top-16 overflow-y-scroll overscroll-contain bg-pink-400">
      <div class="h-[1000px]">
        Scroll independently
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT END -->


    
    <footer class="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-50 bg-gray-700 h-7">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-end px-8 pt-1">
        <div class="text-sm text-white">{versionStr}</div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```